# How to compose bool-returning functions

Tags: f#, function-composition

I have several filter functions with signature `'a -> bool`. I want to create a combined filter that AND's the different filters. I know I can do it like this:

```
let fCombined x =
    f1 x 
    && f2 x
    && f3 x
```

Is there any **more concise** way to directly compose the functions without fully applying them (e.g. by removing `x` from the definition of `fCombined`)?

(I know there are other ways that don't use `bool`, e.g. by using `'a -> 'a option` functions and composing them using `Option.bind`, but that's hardly more concise.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to lose the argument `x`, you can make yourself a special operator:

```
let (&&.) f g x = f x && g x

let fCombined = f1 &&. f2 &&. f3
```

But I don't think this is the kind of thing to worry about. Having the argument is totally fine.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure how to define the operator.